# How to grep query all files for two strings

Tags: bash, command-line, grep, find, combinations

Here we go:

I need to query php files which both have a TODO statement *as well as my name*.
Both strings could be *anywhere* in the document (ie. line) and be positioned anywhere on 0-infinite lines (position 0-n).

**How to grep query for my name:**

```
find -name '*.php' -exec grep -in "fincken" {} +
```

output:

```
./some/file.php:51: ramon fincken
./somefile.php:2: rfincken
```

**How to grep query for the TODOs**

```
find -name '*.php' -exec grep -n "TODO" {} +
```

output:

```
./some/file.php:53: // TODO: foobar!
./some/otherfile.php:53: // TODO: foobar?
```

**I need to combine both grep queries (or their results)** so I am expecting this as result:

```
./some/file.php
```

I have tried operators in one grep, but they expected both strings on the same line and in a particular order or .. came up with all results (OR .. OR) instead of ( AND )

Comment: did you try this `find -name '*.php' -exec grep -n "TODO|fincken" {} +`?

Comment: I did, but that does not return any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line looks ugly, but it should give what you want:

```
find whatever...|xargs grep -il 'fincken'
                |xargs grep -il 'todo'
                |xargs grep -in -e'todo' -e'fincken'
```

The output would look like:

```
/foo/bar/file : 100:TODO
/foo/bar/file : 101:fincken
```

only files with both `TODO` and `fincken` would be listed.

Comment: Note that the first `grep` can be included in the `find` command through the `-exec` flag.

Comment: @fedorqui when I combine find and commands, I prefer xargs. there are discussions on internet, xargs would be a better way to go.

Comment: Interesting, I would've said using `-exec` from `find` would be best to avoid one pipe. +1 for your clear solution. Also note `-i` is not needed in 'todo', because in the question just mentions 'TODO' (capital letters).

Comment: Allright! I have to properly test this , but the results so far are looking good :)

Answer (score 1):

Ask the first `grep` to return just the file name and then pipe to another `grep`:

```
find -name '*.php' -exec grep -li "fincken" {} + | xargs grep -l "TODO"
```

From `man grep`, `-l` (L) returns file name. This way, the `find` comman will return a list of files that will be processed one by one through the `xargs` command.

Your output will be the list of files which contain both "fincken" and "TODO". You can of course pipe more `xargs grep -l` if you want to add more words to find.

---

You can also do use of `grep` alone like this, using `-R` to do a recursive search:

```
grep -Rl --include="*php" "TODO" * | xargs grep -il "fincken"
```

Note I moved the `TODO` grep to be done in the first place, because you use `-i` for "fincken" and it is way slowlier. This way, the `grep -i` will only be run on the already filtered results.

Comment: Allright! I have to properly test this , but the results so far are looking good :)

Comment: @RamonFincken good! Note I added another possible solution using `grep` twice.

Comment: First line of code: 5 sec, second line of code < 3 sec :)

Comment: @RamonFincken note also it is not good practice to post an answer if it is not an answer. Instead, post your thoughts as a comment or edit the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe the first grep through a second one, get the name of the file and skip repetitions:

```
find -name '*.php' -exec grep -in "fincken" {} + | grep TODO | cut -d: -f1 | uniq
```

Comment: Did not give any results :(

Comment: Because I'm dumb and misunderstood the question :)  I think this would make it though: `grep -l TODO \`find -name '*.php' -exec grep -il fincken {} +\``

Comment: Although I think the best answer is the one by fedorqui

Comment: this does the job as well giving me a list of files

Answer (score 0):

People are making this more complicated then it needs to be. `-exec` will take the exit code of the command it runs and use it logically in `find`. So you can just do

```
find -name '*.php' -exec grep -iq "fincken" {} \; -exec grep -iq "TODO" {} \; -print
```

Which will get to the `-print` only if both `-exec` blocks return 0.