# How to grep query all files for 2 strings when filenames have spaces?

Tags: bash, command-line, grep, find, csh

I need to query java files which have both the strings 'rESTWSLib' and '500'.
Both the strings could be anywhere in the document (i.e. line) and can be positioned anywhere on 0-infinite lines (position 0-n).

**How to grep query for 'rESTWSLIB':**

```
find -iname '*.java' -type f -exec grep -l "rESTWSLib" '{}' \; > ~/SMCrestwsList1.txt
```

output:

```
./some/file1.java
./some/file2.java
```

**How to grep query for '500':**

```
find -iname '*.java' -type f -exec grep -l "500" '{}' \; > ~/SMCrestwsList2.txt
```

output:

```
./some/file2.java
./some/file3.java
```

**I need to combine both grep queries (or their results) so I am expecting this as result:**

```
./some/file2.java
```

I have tried the solutions given in [How to grep query all files for 2 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665103/how-to-grep-query-all-files-for-2-strings)

```
find -iname '*.java' -type f -exec grep -l "rESTWSLib" '{}' + | xargs grep -l "500" \; > ~/SMCrestwsList3.txt
```

But, since few files have spaces in their names, only partial output is given with the below error messages:

```
grep: ;: No such file or directory
grep: ./cdrm/bat/OpportunityManagement/Verify: No such file or directory
```

The filename is 'Verify something something'.

How can I tweak this to accept the spaces in the filename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using regex:

```
find -iname '*.java' -type f -exec grep -lzo "rESTWSLib.*500\|500.*rESTWSLib" '{}' \; > ~/SMCrestwsList1.txt
```

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't return any results.

Comment: This only works if the two strings are on the same line.

Comment: @GrishaLevit - forgot about that one, `z` should have it ignore new lines.
@InsecureNoob try it now.

Comment: Unless the files have a null byte :)

Comment: Then they wouldn't be much of a Java source files, would they? ;) (to be fair, OP never claimed that those are Java source files)

Answer (score 1):

To allow filenames with spaces to be processes successfully, you should modify your pipeline by using `grep -Z` and `xargs -0`.  These matching options change `grep` to print filenames separated by a `\0` character and change `xargs` to expect null-separated input strings as well.

```
find . -exec grep -lZ "expr_one" {} \+ | xargs -0 grep -l "expr_two"
```